Updating title in Rmarkdown dynamically
In my flexdashboard, I would like to set the windows title (that is seen in the browser tab) dynamically.
The following mre works. But, when I change the params, I have to render the document two times to see the result in the windows title.
Is there a way to do it in one go? I tried cache=FALSE in the second chunk but that did not help.
---
title: 'Status: `r sprintf("%.0f%%", progress*100)`'
params:
   current_page: 27
   total_pages: 79
output:
   flexdashboard::flex_dashboard: default
   html_document: default
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(bslib)
```

```{r, cache = FALSE}
progress <- with(params, current_page / total_pages)
bslib::value_box(title="Status", value=sprintf("%.0f%%", progress*100))
```


You could use Javascript and {htmltools} to update the content:
## load other libraries
library(htmltools)

put this snippet someplace after the calculation of progress:
```{r, echo = FALSE}
progress_formatted <- sprintf("%.0f%%", progress*100)
tags$script(sprintf("document.querySelector('span.navbar-brand').innerHTML = 'Status: %s'", progress_formatted))
```

However, I think the way to go is to calculate the progress in a/the separate script from which you render the Rmd-template, and hand over the progress together with the other params (current_page and total_pages). Something along the lines of:
total_pages <- 42

Map(1:total_pages,
    f = \(current_page){
       rmarkdown::render('path/to/your_template.Rmd',
                        ## options,
                        params = list(total_pages = total_pages,
                                      current_page = current_page,
                                      progress = current_page / total_pages
                        )
                        
    })



Thanks! Option 1 works fine, I added tags$script(sprintf("document.querySelector('title').innerHTML = 'Status: %s'", progress_formatted)) for updating the windows title.
